# Problems installing RDKit in python 3.8 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04, rdkit

I have had a lot of trouble trying to install RDKit using python3 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Tried to install rdkit this way:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-rdkit
```

But then when I try to import it using python3 it doesn't work. 
It installed indeed, but it is not in the package-list. 
Neither I can import it after using for example:

```
from rdkit import Chem
```

The official web (https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html) site does have the following installation sentence, but it didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rdkit librdkit1 rdkit-data
```

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Why are you not using conda? It's much easier and it works in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

After you've created and activated your conda environment, run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge rdkit
```

Ref: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/rdkit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure rdkit is actually compatible with python 3.8 yet. For example there are no python 3.8 build on conda channel.

Comment: Best one install rdkit via conda and it's conda-forge channel if you want newest possible version.

Answer (score 0):

When apt installs python3-rdkit it puts the packages in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rdkit`, which Python doesn't seem to pick up. I symlinked that folder to the site-packages folder with:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rdkit .
```

and then I could import rdkit in python.

Note: running `apt show python3-rdkit` shows that the package is currently for Python 3.9